Check if welding pattern is welded in simulation
i want to ask something. So i'm planning to simulate welding robot using ros2 and either gazebo or webots, and there will be some pattern on 3D surface to weld.
Is there any way to do draw the pattern and to check if the end-effector of the robot have passed thorugh the pattern in gazebo or webots?
My current planned solution is to store the pattern coordinates (x, y, z) and then check if the end-effector is on that coordinate. But i just think that with this solution the you can't check continous pattern.
So i'm asking if there is a better way/algorithm to check the weld pattern, or maybe to optimize my currently planned solution to check/verify if the weld pattern is welded or not. Thanks
